# Connect microphone with pre-amp to STM32 ADC

Tags: amplifier, adc, stm32, microphone

I need to record audio with STM32. I've got electret microphone and pre-amp based on [MAX9812](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9812-MAX9813L.pdf).

This is a schematic from datasheet:

[image]

How I can connect this pre-amp to the ADC? If I just connect it as-is I will get only positive half of wave, so I need some shift `+Vcc/2`. How can I do this? Maybe I can just remove output capacicator? Also, STM32 has differential ADC. Maybe I can use it here?

Comment: What does the ADC data sheet recommend? Have you read it yet?

Comment: Errrm.  That chip has only a single rail.  Its output would just about have to be at Vcc/2 already.  If you check at pin 3, you can see if it has a DC offset.

Answer (score 1):

MAX9812 has a DC offset of VCC/2 on pin 3 already. So yes, you can drop the capacitor and connect directly.

If this was not the case, you would keep the bypass/FC-blocking capacitor and use a resistor to add the DC component. For example a 100k ohm resistor connected to VCC/2. VCC/2 can be made with a voltage divider of say 1k ohm resistors.